# While loop just condition VS with content

Tags: while-loop

I have a question about while loop

In my function GetEvent()

```
static bool event = false;

void callbackFunc()
{
    event = true;
}

bool GetEvent()
{
    while (event == false );

    return true;
}
```

This function will return true when callback function set 'event' valiable as 'true'

But it seems this 'event' valiable doesn't change to 'true' even if callback function change it to 'true'

Because while loop doesn't break when callback function delivered and set 'event' as true.

So when I put the contents in while just like

```
static bool event = false;

void callbackFunc()
{
    event = true;
}

bool GetEvent()
{
    while (event == flase )
    {
        /* Wait for 10ms in every loop */
        tv.tv_sec = 0;
        tv.tv_nsec = nMilliSec*1000000;
        nanosleep(&tv, NULL);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then seems 'event' gets true then out from while loop and return true.

Is this scheduling issue?

**UPDATED**

1. while condition has updated.
2. Callback function and event declaration example.

Comment: The first function will return true when `event` is `false`.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in condition, please have a look again.

Comment: How did you declare `event`?

Comment: Nothing here is setting event to any value... both loops will return when event is set to not false. Can you add the code that sets the event? Also, can you please be clear: what behaviour do you expect? what are you getting instead?

Comment: I expected getting out of while loop when 'event' gets changed as 'true' by 'callbackFunc' but it's not when first while loop without contents but only condition.

Comment: That first code is a straight-up busy-wait anyway and that's stupendously bad code in and of itself.  As such, the fact that it doesn't do what you want is completely irrelevant because you should never use it regardless.  What are you actually trying to achieve?  There is undoubtedly a better way because you've shown is just plain bad.

Comment: Can you add `volatile` before your declaration of `event` and try again?

Comment: @jmcilhinney In this while I tend to wait GetEvent function returns true until the callback arrived.

Comment: It doesn't matter why you're doing it.  Any busy-wait is bad code and should never be used.  The whole point of a callback is it tells you when an operation is finished and allows you to do something at that point.  The code you have makes no sense and should be thrown out.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Then how about second code while loop with contents (waiting 10ms)? Does it makes sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense as you've written it. I don't know whether this is some contrived simplification of a real situation but, as I said, the whole point of a callback is to provide notification that a task has completed and to let to perform an action when it completes.  You're inherently waiting for the callback by doing nothing, so doing something explicit to wait for it is pointless. I suggest that you explain the real situation so that we can try to provide a real solution. If what you've shown is what you've got then it's just plain wrong because your `GetEvent` doesn't get `event`.